# The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher when flutter run

Tags: flutter, kotlin, gradle

When I try to build my Flutter project with `flutter run` I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':location' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.20

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 31s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             33,1s
```

This is the full error but it looks to me like I already have 1.6.10 as a Kotlin Version which is already higher than 1.5.20

[image]

Does anyone have experience with this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Intellij (Android Studio) -> Tools -> Kotlin -> Configure Kotlin Plugin Updates -> Make sure it is up to date. This looks like an editor problem not a gradle problem

Comment: How did you solved this issue; if you did succeeded?

Answer (score 0):

In dependency section you have assigned $kotlin_version.
So, rather than that you can do something like below:

```
dependencies {
  classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10"
}
```

Comment: already tried, it doesn't make a difference

Comment: Make sure you fix the correct build.gradle script file in the project for example project ':capacitor-community-admob'

Comment: @OverdoseB12
Kindly share your solution if you have, as I am having a similar issue. Been battling for days

Answer (score 0):

Kept the ext.kotlin_version in the build script but upgrading version to 1.6.21 solved the problem for me try this one.

```
buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.21'
  repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle plugin:$kotlin_version"
  }
}
```

Source : https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/287/your-project-requires-newer-version-of-kotlin-gradle-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be caused by the 'location' dart package, and I see a github issue was opened for it:  https://github.com/Lyokone/flutterlocation/issues/838

Answer (score 0):

it seems like the `location: ^4.4.0` package was using the 1.4.20 version

remove the `location` package  from dependencies and it should work!!!

then add `publish_to: none` in pubspec.yaml below `version:` then add these lines below in the dependencies don't forget to give it a proper indentation.

location:

```
git:

  url: https://github.com/781flyingdutchman/flutterlocation.git
  ref: V4
  path: packages/location.
```

Answer (score -1):

This is related to Location package, I have resolved this issue by by upgrading Location package to the latest version so far,

changing location package from location: ^4.4.0 To location: ^5.0.3 in pubspec.yaml file